# Contextual Voice Commands Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

what I'm trying to do is to make an activity which should be able to display the "ok, glass" command to open contextual voice commands.
I already achieved it but only when I tap on the Touchpad of the activity. Is there a possibility that when I say "OK, glass" --> Start App --> then it should show my live card and afterwards the "ok, glass" appears?

Looking forward to your answers
Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the `LiveCard` [Dev Guide](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/live-cards#supporting_contextual_voice):

1. Indicate that your MenuActivity supports contextual voice commands:

   ```
   // Initialize your LiveCard as usual.
   mLiveCard.setVoiceActionEnabled(true);
   mLiveCard.publish(LiveCard.PublishMode.REVEAL); // or SILENT
   ```
2. Modify your MenuActivity to support invocation through the voice flow:

   ```
   /**
    * Activity showing the options menu.
    */
   public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

       private boolean mFromLiveCardVoice;
       private boolean mIsFinishing;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           mFromLiveCardVoice =
                   getIntent().getBooleanExtra(LiveCard.EXTRA_FROM_LIVECARD_VOICE, false);
           if (mFromLiveCardVoice) {
               // When activated by voice from a live card, enable voice commands. The     menu
               // will automatically "jump" ahead to the items (skipping the guard phrase
               // that was already said at the live card).
               getWindow().requestFeature(WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onAttachedToWindow() {
           super.onAttachedToWindow();
           if (!mFromLiveCardVoice) {
               openOptionsMenu();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu) {
           if (isMyMenu(featureId)) {
               getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.stopwatch, menu);
               return true;
           }
           return super.onCreatePanelMenu(featureId, menu);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onPreparePanel(int featureId, View view, Menu menu) {
           if (isMyMenu(featureId)) {
               // Don't reopen menu once we are finishing. This is necessary
               // since voice menus reopen themselves while in focus.
               return !mIsFinishing;
           }
           return super.onPreparePanel(featureId, view, menu);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
           if (isMyMenu(featureId)) {
               // Handle item selection.
               switch (item.getItemId()) {
                   case R.id.stop_this:
                       stopService(new Intent(this, StopwatchService.class));
                       return true;
               }
           }
           return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
       }

       @Override
       public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {
           super.onPanelClosed(featureId, menu);
           if (isMyMenu(featureId)) {
               // When the menu panel closes, either an item is selected from the menu or the
               // menu is dismissed by swiping down. Either way, we end the activity.
               isFinishing = true;
               finish();
           }
       }

       /**
        * Returns {@code true} when the {@code featureId} belongs to the options menu or     voice
        * menu that are controlled by this menu activity.
        */
       private boolean isMyMenu(int featureId) {
           return featureId == Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL ||
                  featureId == WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS;
       }
   }
   ```